# How to get all the sequences and columns to which sequence is applied using single query

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-sequence

I want to get all the sequences created, tables and columns to which that sequence is applied in a database using a single query in PostgreSQL. Any direct or indirect method is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.relname as related_table, a.attname as related_column,s.relname as sequence_name 
FROM pg_class s 
   JOIN pg_depend d ON d.objid = s.oid 
   JOIN pg_class t ON d.objid = s.oid AND d.refobjid = t.oid 
   JOIN pg_attribute a ON (d.refobjid, d.refobjsubid) = (a.attrelid, a.attnum) 
   JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = s.relnamespace 
WHERE s.relkind     = 'S' 
AND n.nspname = 'public'
```

i found the above query which will return list of tables, columns and related sequences.

source: http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1667561-How-to-list-sequences-and-the-columns-by-SQL